# Which Intel processor in notebook

Tags: intel-core-i7, intel-core-i5

I soon gonna need a new laptop to use Visual Studio 2010 professional and SQL Server 2008.

I don't know if gonna buy a notebook with processor Core i5 or i7.

Which processor should I use?

// Fullmetalboy

Comment: Please take a look at the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq) before you post. This question is a shopping recommendation and therefore considered off-topic here.

Comment: for a more generic guide to _how_ you can figure out for yourself what hardware to choose, please read [how do I know what hardware to buy to meet my needs](http://superuser.com/questions/297274/). Specific shopping recommendations are not permitted on Super User though, as @slhck explained.

Comment: Not to forget [our excellent blog post](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/06/20/qotw-how-should-i-choose-hardware/) about the very same subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it all depends. An i7 is going to outperform the i5. Do you want a faster (at compiling, etc) machine or do you want $$ to spend on other things? Of course, once you buy that laptop, the only feasible way to upgrade the CPU is to get a new(er) one.