# Disable all interface styles(skins, themes) in windows 8 or and alternative windows like operating system

Tags: windows-8

I am looking for ways to disable all interface styles in windows 8 and run in command line(something like command prompt looks like

or some classic interface(windows classic like(98), like windows 7 looks in the classic theme).

I cant replace the Operatig system to windows 7, I will not go into details why, I just can't.

An alternative solution would be a free Operating System that is "windows like" 
It needs to be "windows like" because I need to run Windows Applications (Adobe Suite and more).

My configuration is:
Intel Core i53350P @3.10Ghz 3.30Ghz
8.00 GB RAM Memory
With 1GB Video Memory on Radeon HD 5500

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Windows 8 Theme which offers a Classic Look:

[image]

http://xxinightxx.deviantart.com/art/Windows-Classic-Vs-372853688

You must install [UxStyle](http://uxstyle.com/) or patch the Uxtheme DLLs to use such themes.

Answer (score 1):

Your Computer is enough powerful for any Windows. The User Interface of `Windows` can not be disabled - a Windows without the windows would not make sense.

If you don't like the Windows 8 design, then stick with **Windows 7 or XP**. Otherwise there are plenty of [Linux alternatives](https://superuser.com/questions/512588/choosing-a-linux-distribution) with [wine](http://wiki.winehq.org/) to run windows applications.

Comment: Turns out my wireless keyboard and mouse were not working properly at times and I thought it was because of video hardware/software problems... but the signal was low and the mouse stopped at times and this is what caused the problem..

With a wired keyboard and mouse everything works as its supposed to.
Sorry for the trouble, maybe I still get interesting answers on this, I see a lot of complaint about windows8 on the internets

http://www2.mes-coloriages-preferes.com/Images/Large/Famous-characters-Troll-face-Troll-face-poker-177134.png

Comment: Linux is not good, I need to run Adobe suite, no Linux versions only windows and MacOS

Comment: You gave the answer already within your question: Windows 7 with the classic theme. If MacOS and Linux aren't an alternative, there are no more other alternative operating systems in our galaxy...

Comment: I also said in the question that "I cant replace the Operatig system to windows 7"